# Is there a way to "View Pending Changes" in TFS from the Source Control View in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, merge

We have 3 branches: Main, Dev, Release.

If I do my work in Dev, then want to merge the changes, I first Check-In my Dev project.  Then I go to the Source Control View and first merge Main into Dev (just in case), then check Dev in (again), then merge Dev into Main, then checkin Main (again).

Without opening the main project, is there a way I can view the pending changes (say, view the pending changes on Main before I check it in the second time).  I don't think there should be any, but it would be nice to know exactly what is different with this checkin.

I think this makes more sense from the first checkin of Main.  What if I accidentally opened the Main project one day and was mucking around? I might be checking in something I've forgotten about, and I can't seem to find a quick way to check this from the Source Control View.

Thanks

**Pictures of My Setup**

[image: Source Control View]

[image]

Comment: When I right click on a branch in Source Control I have the view pending changes item in the context menu.

Comment: I can't seem to find that option.  Images attached

Comment: @Tyler DeWitt: in your first screenshot, look at the bottom tab row.  Just click "Pending Changes" to open the Pending Changes view.  Or go to View > Other Windows > Pending Changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pending changes window shows everything in the current workspace that is checked out. Is that what you are looking for? You can filter this list by the current solution, but it will also show the entire workspace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181400.aspx

Comment: You can show only the changes within a folder (or an entire project) by invoking view pending changes from the context menu of the folder in source control.

Comment: I was looking to avoid using the workspace because that would require me to open the Main project just to check it in.

Comment: @Tyler DeWitt: using a TFS workspace does not require you to open any project.

Comment: I was forgetting about the Pending Changes view. Thanks